# how to annotate a python 3 factory method that returns an object of a child class?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, python-typing

I am trying to write a factory method that returns an instance of a dynamic class inheriting from an abstract class. The factory works, but I do not know how to annotate properly the methods:

```py
class ClientBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection):
        self._connection = connection

class BuildClient(ClientBase):
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection):
        super().__init__(connection)

def _get_client(full_class_name: str, connection) -> ???:
    def _get_class(full_class_name: str) -> ???:
        module_name, class_def = (__package__ + full_class_name).rsplit('.', 1)
        imported = import_module(module_name)
        return getattr(imported, class_def)

    client_class = _get_class(full_class_name)
    return client_class(connection)

class ClientFactory:
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection):
        self._connection = connection

    def get_client(self, client_type: str) -> ???:
        full_class_name = f'.{client_type}.{client_type}_client.{client_type.capitalize()}Client'
        return _get_client(full_class_name, self._connection)
```

What I do not know to express is the annotations for ClientFactory.get_client and _get_client (also it's internal method). I can annotate the return types for _get_client and _get_class as

```py
def _get_client(full_class_name: str, connection) -> ClientBase:
    def _get_class(full_class_name: str) -> Type[ClientBase]:
```

and they pass the static checker (of PyCharm), but then I do not know how to annotate the return type of get_client, given that it can come from a number of classes (note that full_class_name gets created on the fly).

Any ideas? Is this possible, at all?

Comment: A static type checker doesn't execute your code. It just reads it. Even if you could come up with a construct to annotate this, no type checker will ever know how to infer the type, if it depends on runtime logic of your program, which in this case it obviously does. The best thing you can do is annotate it with some common type that all possible return types descend from, if such a thing exists.

Comment: PS: This is one reason why I try to avoid something like dynamic imports like the plague. There are almost always better options to conditionally use different classes. Especially, since it seems here that you actually _do_ expect that "client" to have a certain type, as opposed to just any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, if you were writing this in a strongly typed language like C++ or Java, the return type of `get_client()` would be `ClientBase`. If the caller needs to cast to a more specific type, the language allows them to do that (in Python you would use `typing.cast()`).

Tangentially, I would generally argue that the caller shouldn't need to know the type more specifically than `ClientBase`, but that's not the topic of this question, so I guess I'll leave it at that.